# How to write to a txt file in Servlet and automatically download it when requests

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to create a txt file in my Servlet and automatically download it at the client side when client requests. I have below code to write to a txt, but it gives access denied error in Netbeans IDE using glassfishserver. How can I do it?

```
 //File creation
 String strPath = "C:\\example.txt";
 File strFile = new File(strPath);
 boolean fileCreated = strFile.createNewFile();
 //File appending
 Writer objWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(strFile));
 objWriter.write("This is a test");
 objWriter.flush();
 objWriter.close();
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with that path `"C:\\example.txt";` ?? you need to understand the Web concept and how does it work. You can not access your local file from server.

Comment: @Shafin Mahmud thats what i'm asking, how can i create a txt file in the server and download it from client side

Comment: check my answer @virat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a thing you do it in JSP. You better have a `Servlet` and just create a `Outputstream` and put your text in it. Then flush that stream into the `HttpServletResponse`.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/txt")
public class TextServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"example.txt\"");
        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            String outputResult = "This is Test";
            outputStream.write(outputResult.getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Remember you need to set the content-type `text/plain` and a `Content-Disposition` header that mentions filename and tells broswer that it should be downloaded as file attachment.

This is what **Content-Disposition** header is about in concise description

> In a regular HTTP response, the Content-Disposition response header is
>   a header indicating if the content is expected to be displayed inline
>   in the browser, that is, as a Web page or as part of a Web page, or as
>   an attachment, that is downloaded and saved locally.

If you are a beginner. You may like to learn more about from this

- [What is HTTP, Structure of HTTP Request and Response?](https://www.webnots.com/what-is-http/)
- [How a Servlet Application works](https://www.studytonight.com/servlet/how-a-servlet-application-work.php)
- [Difference Between Servlet and JSP](https://javabeat.net/difference-servlet-jsp/)